# Is there a way to display a '1/2' integer to a show up as a 'yes/no' String?

Tags: jsf

I've loaded content from a database and it displays as 1 or 2 and I would like to convert it to yes for 1 and no for 2, is there any converter for this?

Comment: There is many way to do that... either in the bean or in the xhtml (by condition)

Comment: I've looked at all the xhtml converters but non seem to convert from a integer to String. I've only found from String to Integer.

Comment: you can always create custom converters... but if it just for display, use the view side solution below

Answer (score 0):

**Bean side solution**

```
class Bean
{
    private Integer myvalue;

    public String getValue()
    {
        return (myvalue == 1 ? : "yes" : "no");
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
#{bean.value}
```

**View side solution**

```
class Bean
{
    private Integer myvalue;

    public Integer getMyValue()
    {
        return myvalue;
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
#{bean.myValue eq 1 ? 'yes' : 'no'}
```

Note : these solutions have not been tested, the second one may need to be treated as a Long.